# How to loop a section of code under the loop branch only once in Arduino?

Tags: loops, arduino

I've been struggling with some code lately. Just like I mentioned in my question, I want to loop a single section of code under the `loop()` block only once. I have done my research and am aware of the two common ways to do this. One is to put the code I want to run once in the `setup()` block and the second being using the `while(1)` statement in the `loop()` block. Unfortunately, both ways are not suitable for my code. The first reason is it is compulsory for my code to be in the `loop()` section. I cannot use the second option as *all* the code under the `loop()` block ends up running once. Like I said before, I want only a *section* of code in the `loop()` block to run once.

For your information, the purpose of this code is to display in an LCD, the amount of milliliters left for the user to drink for a healthy water consumption. For example, a person should drink min 1800ml a day for proper hydration. If the user drinks 123ml of water, LCD should display (1800-123).

```cpp
 //Adds the liquid crystal library 
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//defines lcd pin numbers
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

// defines ultra sonic sensor pin numbers
const int trigPin = 8;
const int echoPin = 7;

// defines variables
long duration;
long volume;
long interval = 3600000; //1 hour
unsigned long stime = millis();
double pdist = 0;
double cdist = 0; 
double mcons = 4.5; //128ml;

void setup() {
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication 
lcd.begin(16, 2); // Starts the lcd communication 
}

void loop() {
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);

// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

// Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

//Converting the distance to cm
double cdist = duration / 29 / 2;

//Finding volume of the water
double volume_of_rem_height = 3.14*3*3*(cdist);
Serial.println(1800-volume_of_rem_height);

//I WANT ONLY THE BELOW STATEMENT TO BE RUN ONCE. REST ALL SHOULD CONTINUE 
//TO LOOP.
lcd.print(1800-volume_of_rem_height);
```

Comment: If you want to do something specific number of times, you usually introduce a counter.

Comment: I think this is an x-y problem: Most probably, you don't want the value to be sent to the display *whenever it changes*. If you really want it done only once, you should really re-consider putting it into `setup()`

Comment: Your question is probably better suited for the Arduino sub-site: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @tofro I do want to update the display whenever it changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino ruleas are easy:

1. Everything you want to be done exactly once when the Arduino is switched on, needs to go into `init`
2. Everything else neeeds to go into `loop`(at least, into `loop`'s callchain.)
3. If you want something *not done* on every iteration on `loop`, stop the Arduino doing that by explicitly checking

Init two values of variables in `init`:

```
currentValue = lastValue = 0;
```

In `loop`, check whether something has changed from the last iteration, if yes, do the display update:

```
currentValue = 1800 - volume_of_rem_height
if (currentValue != lastValue) {
   lastValue = currentValue;
   lcd.print (currentValue)
}
```

This will only do the print once `currentValue` has really changed from the last iteration.

Comment: I've figured out how to do it. Thanks for these tips. I'll keep them in mind :)